# Creating Method in C#

Tags: c#

I have about 9 of these just with different values for were "sourceVal" and "Source" is. I would like to make a method and just pass those two values for each one so my code is cleaner. Is there an easy way to make a method out of this?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int?, string> sourceVal in Source) {
            try {
                if (p.LeadOriginDetail != null) {
                    if (sourceVal.Value.ToUpper() == p.LeadOriginDetail.ToUpper()) {
                        sourceid = sourceVal.Key;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        sourceid = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    sourceid = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                CPCUtilities.LogGeneral("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want culture dependent compares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to refactor it manually, try this:

```
int? Find(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> items, string origin) {
    int? resId = null;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int?, string> sourceVal in items) {
        try {
            if (origin != null) {
                if (sourceVal.Value.ToUpper() == origin.ToUpper()) {
                    resId = sourceVal.Key;
                    break;
                } else {
                    resId = null;
                }
            } else {
                resId = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CPCUtilities.LogGeneral("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    return resId;
}
```

Now you can invoke this logic as follows:

```
var sourceId = Find(Source, p.LeadOriginDetail);
var marketId = Find(Market, p.LeadOriginDetail);
var businessUnitId = Find(BusinessUnit, p.LeadOriginDetail);
```

There is an easier way of getting the first matching ID using LINQ - it is nearly always a better choice than rolling your own loop, let alone making nine similar loops.

Comment: Thanks. I have several of these and all dont have Source or Sourceid, for example one is Market and Marketid and one is BusinessUnits and BusinessId. Anyway to make this work with that? Thanks!

Comment: @Justin are the types of `BusinessUnits`, `Market`, etc. all `IDictionary<int?,string>`?

Comment: @Justin You can use the same method for all of them, I edited the answer to make this point easier to see.

Comment: @CodeInChaos That's right, I guess I could have inferred that from the usage (after all, there aren't that many classes with the `ToUpper()` method returning a `string` :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, rewrite it to use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) and then you can easily write that into a method (return type `int?` and parameter `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?, string>>`).

Comment: I would just use    `sourceid = Source
        .FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value.ToUpper() == p.LeadOriginDetail.ToUpper()).Key;`

Answer (score 1):

Select your code. `Right click > Refactor > Extract Method`.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array using `new ClassName[] { }` syntax:

```
foreach([itemclass] Source in new [collectionclass][] { Source1, Source2, Source3, Source4... }) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int?, string> sourceVal in Source) { 
        // everything else
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Method called YourSampleMethod();//for example and rename it to what ever you want the method name to be

```
    private static void YourSampleMethod()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int?, string> sourceVal in Source) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                if (p.LeadOriginDetail != null)
                { 
                    if (sourceVal.Value.ToUpper() == p.LeadOriginDetail.ToUpper())
                    { 
                        sourceid = sourceVal.Key; break; 
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        sourceid = null; 
                    } 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    sourceid = null; 
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                CPCUtilities.LogGeneral("Error: " + ex.ToString()); 
            } 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "different value for sourceVal" as sourceVal is a local variable to the loop.

But if the problem is that you have different types that can replace "Source" type, then you extract the snippet into a method that accepts an argument of type

```
  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?, string>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a method like the following:

```
int? FindKeyForValue(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?,string> sequence,string valueToFind)
{
    if(valueToFind!=null)
        return sequence
            .Where(string.Equals(pair.Value,valueToFind,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(pair=>pair.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    else
        return null;
}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
int? FindKeyForValue(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int?,string> sequence,string valueToFind)
{
    if(valueToFind!=null)
        return sequence
            .FirstOrDefault(string.Equals(pair.Value,valueToFind,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Key;
    else
        return null;
}
```

which is shorter, but IMO harder to read.

You should choose the culture to use deliberately. In most cases you'll want to use an invariant culture, not the current culture. I used the current culture in my code, since that's closest to your original code.